# Mono.subscribe() to throw an exception back to the client

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, subscribe

I have been tried to find out why the Runtime exception is not propagated back to the client. I have the next piece of code, so when I return a Mono.error this should be handled in the subscribe error section, to throw an exception to the client, but this is not happening. Any idea about I am doing wrong?

```
    public void onmethod(EventDetails eventDetails, String eventType) {
        messageConverter.convertAndSendMessage(eventType, eventDetails)
                .flatMap(aBoolean -> {
                    if (aBoolean)
                        log.debug("Event published");
                    else {
                        log.debug("Problem publishing event.");
                        return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Problem publishing event."));
                    }
                    return Mono.just(true);
                })
                .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Failed to consume message", throwable))
                .subscribe(
                        next -> { } ,
                        error -> {
                            throw Exceptions.propagate(error);
                        }
                );
}
```

And this is the test I have to verify the method behaviour. This test fails as any exception is thrown. However, I can see in the logs that the exception happens.

```
        Assertions.assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () ->
                consentsListener.onmethod(
                        eventDetails, "eventType")
        );
```

```
19:44:32.463 [main] ERROR events.auth.ConsentsListenerImpl - Failed to consume message
java.lang.RuntimeException: Problem publishing event. 
    at events.auth.ConsentsListenerImpl.lambda$publishMessage$0(ConsentsListenerImpl.java:121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:152)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4084)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4214)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4070)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4006)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3978)
    at ...

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected java.lang.RuntimeException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
```

Thank you very much in advance.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have been tried to find out why the Runtime exception is not propagated back to the client.

Because you're subscribing to it, which is almost certainly the wrong thing to do. The framework (Webflux in this case) should be what controls the subscription to your publisher.

If you remove your `subscribe()` call on that chain, change your method to return `Mono<Boolean>` and then *return* the entire chain in that method, it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I know that should happen and that's the correct way to work with reactive. However, for different reasons I need to understand a code that I found that was doing what I have explained. 

Subscribe() means asynchronous, so that we should not wait for any response or any exception (this is my understanding), however the test was green with Springboot version 2.3.x, but it turns into red with version 2.4.x (this is what I expect as the call is asynchronous).

We should use block() if we want to check the exception or any other result. I think.

Comment: Could you link to a full project somewhere we can clone and then use to take a look? I still think the behaviour you're seeing could essentially be undefined because of how you're subscribing, but it may be a discrepancy in behaviour between the versions.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot share the code. Anyway, I'll change that part cause as you said I think we shouldn't have that. Thanks a lot.